# How to get filename from random picturebox?

Tags: c#, winforms, random, picturebox

I have a question, I'm making a guess app and clicking the button PictureBox to get a random image from the directory.

```
Random rnd = new Random();

private void random_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string folder = @"D:\folder";
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);

    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = files[rnd.Next(files.Length)];
}
```

And now I want to make if statement. If the picture name is "apple.png" do this, if "orange.png" do this. Can I make something like this?

Cheers and have a good day!

Comment: What are you putting into the `ImageLocation` property?

Comment: Why are you getting the files from the directory on every click?

Comment: because I want to randomize the images (maybe 50,100?), when I randomize the image I enter the numbers in the textbox and calculate the result of the guesser game. For every image i must get name to calculate the different result

Comment: Well, you set the ImageLocation  property, so you can test it, no? Watch out for the whole path, though..1

Answer (score 0):

okey, i got it alone...

If someone is looking for it:

```
string filePath = pictureBox1.ImageLocation;
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

if (fileName == "yourfilename.png")
{
 do this
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).